# prototype question - in a Ruby on Rails view how do I trigger a remote AJAX call? (i.e. like "link_to_remote" but directly without the link)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prototype

I have a prototype question in the context of Ruby on Rails.

**QUESTION - In a rails view how do I trigger a remote AJAX call?**

ie. like "link_to_remote" but directly without the link - so I want specifically in my case when the windows loads to be able to trigger a remote call to populate data in a DIV via a remote call...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [Ajax functions](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request) provided by Prototype. No rails-magic required.